# What is this error that pops up when trying to run Steam, and how do I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, steam

This error message keeps on appearing when I try to run steam.exe. I dont believe that I did anything to my computer before I started getting these errors. I am running windows 10.Below is a screen shot of the error. It seems to have something to do with internet explorer, which makes no sense as steam has nothing in common with IE.

[image: Steam error]

Comment: It appears you are trying to use a shortcut to steam that does not work anymore. Have you tried navigating directly to Steam and launching it from there? It would be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam`

Comment: Did you try to reinstall

Comment: Looks like you have a broken shortcut to Steam.  Try launching Steam directly out of its installation directory.  Edit your question to include the necessary information to answer your question.